# Solving Linear Congruences With The Euler Totient Functio

Tags: number-theory

I've been asked to calcualte $15^{123456789012345}$ mod $2500$. Now I worked out $\varphi(2500)=1000$ but I can't use Euler's theorem here because $1000$ and $2500$ aren't coprime. Can anyone offer some assistance with how to tackle this calculation?

Answer (score 2):

$15^k$ mod $2500$ repeats with period $2$ starting at $k=4$:

$$15, 225, 875, 625, 1875, 625, 1875, 625, 1875, ...$$

Since your exponent $123456789012345$ is odd, the answer is $1875$.

Answer (score 2):

The general method consists in using the Chinese Remainder Theorem: $$\mathbf Z/2500\mathbf Z\simeq \mathbf Z/625\mathbf Z\times \mathbf Z/4\mathbf Z$$
Computing any power modulo $2500$ amounts to computing the same power modulo $625$ and modulo $4$, then assembling the results modulo $2500$.

\begin{align*}15^n \bmod 4= 3^n \bmod 4&= 1&&\text{if $n$ is even}\\&=3 &&\text{if $n$ is odd} \end{align*}
so here $15^n\equiv 3$.

Modulo $625=5^4$, $15^n=3^n\cdot 5^n\equiv 0$ as soon as $n\ge 4$, which is the case here.

*Reconstruction modulo* $2500$: we use Bézout's identity: $$625-156\cdot 4 =1, $$ so the image of the pair $(0,3)$ by the reciprocal of the canonical morphism is $$3\cdot 625-0\cdot156\cdot4 =1875.$$

Comment: Nice answer (+1).  I was wondering what theorems could justify my observation (that ended up being correct in retrospect).  Using the Totient function seems overkill, I guess.

Comment: Right. The only place here for the Totient function is modulo 4, where it is hardly useful…